# creating custom page template

Tags: theming, 8

How do you create a custom page layout in Drupal 8? In drupal 7 you could do something like page--about.tpl or something. How do we do that in drupal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable twig debugging by copying default.services.yml to services.yml and following instructions in the twig.config section. The debugging comments will display template file name hints in HTML comments in the page output.

Comment: from what I have read templates are only based on internal paths and exclude the url alias.